# Button automatic HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button and this onclick to see a animation on the page that effect is for the id **iterrateEffects** but I need is effect init automatic (10 sec.), I see on internet is possible with the **getElementById** but a can't to put other id, Can I to use other tag for the effect? or other function in javascript.

Thanks!

```
<button id="iterateEffects" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: post the rest of your code so we can see the your js function.

Comment: Can you please show the JS you currently have? Also your question is not clear. Please try to improve it as much as you can.

Answer (score -2):

If you want something to run after a set amount of time use javascript **setTimeout**

```
setTimeout(function () {animate()}, 10000);
```

The above code will run once after 10 seconds depending on where you put it (i.e. after page load or after click of an event).

The function **animate()** that I pass to it is the function to run to make your animation do whatever you like

Comment: Why am I downvoted? She asked how to run something after 10 seconds? If anyone gives me a good answer I'll be surprised

Comment: I have this button by pressing the button mentioned above an animation of a css file I want to do is run the animation automatically, an option that I saw running is to run the button with JavaScript but this requires an ID, but this tag already has an ID that is the result of the animation so that I can not run it, I think I should change the tag button and someone else to run every n time but it is not clear which can fulfill this role.